# Общие делители (программа не работает)

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, олимпиада, факторизация

Для заданного целого положительного числа n найдите количество таких целых чисел x, лежащих в отрезке [1,n], что количество общих делителей у n и x равно заданному числу k. Например, если k=1, то требуется найти количество чисел, взаимнопростых c n, которые не превосходят его.

Входные данные
В единственной строке входных данных через пробел заданы два целых положительных числа n и k (1≤n,k≤5000).

Выходные данные
Выведите одно целое число — искомое количество.

Примеры

входные данные
2 1
выходные данные
1

входные данные
12 2
выходные данные
4

входные данные
13 1
выходные данные
12

входные данные
720 6
выходные данные
52

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
while a <= b:
        m = 0
        for i in range(1, a + 1):
            if a % i == 0:
                m += 1
        if m >= n:
            print(a, '-', m, end=' - ')
            for i in range(1, a + 1):
                if a % i == 0:
                    print(i, end=' ')
            print()
        a += 1
```

Вообще программа не идет, если не трудно напишите код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6):

Эх, не знаю я Python... Может, кто переведет?

**Не актуально - см. ниже :)**

Немного теории.
Все общие делители двух чисел определяются разложением НОД этих чисел на простые сомножители. Если НОД `G` имеет разложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то количество общих делителей может быть записано как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Число 5000 небольшое, так что факторизацию можно выполнять прямо по массиву простых чисел - их всего лишь 19, которые меньше квадратного корня из 5000.

По-моему, самый быстрый путь.

Код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int gcd(int m, int n)  // Поиск наибольшего общего делителя
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return m + n;
}

// Все возможные простые делители чисел до 5000
int primes[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67 };

// Проверка числа на k общих делителей
bool cnt(int n, int m, int k)
{
    int g = gcd(n,m);            // НОД
    int total = 1;               // Количество общих делителей

    // факторизуем НОД на простые сомножители; количество делителей -
    // произведение их степеней, увеличенных на 1
    for(int i = 0; g > 1 && i < size(primes); ++i)
    {
        int l = 0;
        while(g%primes[i] == 0) { g /= primes[i]; ++l; }
        total *= l+1;
    }
    return total == k;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n, k, count = 0;
    cin >> n >> k;

    // Перебор всех чисел
    for(int m = 1; m < n; ++m)
        if (cnt(n,m,k)) count++;

    cout << count << endl;
}
```

[Сравнение](https://ideone.com/eSjD7K) для 5000 2 с [кодом @Psyperception](https://ideone.com/vlY9Q3) по времени дает нефиксируемое :) время против 1.3 секунды...

С помощью напильника, Интернета и какой-то... [перевел сам](https://ideone.com/7UjPn9):

```
def gcd(m,n):
    while m>0 and n>0:
        if m < n : 
            n = n % m
        else:
            m = m % n
    return m + n;

primes = [ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67 ]

def cnt(n,m,k):
    g = gcd(n,m)    
    total = 1

    for i in range(19):
        if g <= 1: break
        l = 0
        while g%primes[i] == 0:
            g = g // primes[i]
            l = l + 1
        total = total * (l+1)
    return total == k

n = int(input('n: '))
k = int(input('k: '))
count = 0
for m in range(1,n):
    if cnt(n,m,k) != 0: count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Должен заметить, что этот код на том же примере `5000 2`, что у @Psyperception выполняется за 1.3 секунды, у меня выполняется за 0.02 секунды - так, всего в 65 раз быстрее :)

Comment: 0.02 секунды - столько стартует Питон с пустой программой. Ваше время видимо ещё ниже, а ускорение больше.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
n = int(input('Введите число n: '))
k = int(input('Введите количество общих делителей k: '))
# эта функция возвращает количество всех общих 
делителей
def all_deliteli(a,b):
n = 0
for i in range(1, min(a, b) + 1):
    if a % i == b % i == 0:
        n += 1
return n
count_chisel = 0 # счетчик
""" Тут мы начинаем циклом проходить от 1 до указанного числа n.
    Проверяем общее число делителей двух чисел: 1 и 1, потом 
    1 и 2, 1 и 3 и т.д """
for x in range(1, n + 1):
    all_gcd = all_deliteli(x, n)
    if all_gcd == k: # Если число делителей совпадает с нашим 
указанным числом k, то мы увеличиваем счетчик
        count_chisel += 1 # вот тут
print(count_chisel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Эта задача решается просто и быстро если завести массив счётчиков общих делителей. Первоначально он заполнен единицами - любое число делится на единицу. Для любого *d* - делителя *n* из диапазона *[2, n]* на единицу увеличиваются счётчики с индексами *d*, *2d*, *3d*, ... . По окончании цикла счётчик по индексу *i* содержит количество делителей общих для *i* и *n*.

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
a = [1] * (n + 1)
a[0] = 0
for d in range(2, n + 1):
    if n % d == 0:
        for i in range(d, n + 1, d):
            a[i] += 1
print(a.count(k))
```